# File Size & disk avail size is not working inside if else condition in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Inside shell script i need to transfer 1 file from 1 UNIX server to another UNIX server. So we need to check file size & disk available size of target server. If file size is greater than disk available size then job should get failed. So I echo both value but in if else condition it is not working properly.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=${1}
FILE=${2}
SFTP_USER=${3}
SFTP_PATH=${4}
SFTP_HOST=${5}
SFTP_PORT=${6}
tgt_path=${7}
FILE_SIZE=`stat -c %s ${DIR}/${FILE}`
echo "Size of the file = $FILE_SIZE"

sftp -o BatchMode=yes -oPort=${SFTP_PORT} ${SFTP_USER}@${SFTP_HOST} <<EOF > ${DIR}/logs/script_wr.log
cd ${SFTP_PATH}
mkdir ${tgt_path}
DISK_AVAIL_SIZE=`df -B1 ${SFTP_PATH}/${tgt_path}`
echo "Disk Available size = ${DISK_AVAIL_SIZE}"
if [ ${FILE_SIZE} -lt ${DISK_AVAIL_SIZE} ]
then
    put ${DIR}/${FILE} ${SFTP_PATH}/${tgt_path}
    ls -l ${SFTP_PATH}/${tgt_path}/${FILE}
else 
    echo "Job got failed as File size is greater than the disk available size of target server."
    exit 1
fi
EOF

...............
echo "File transfer has been completed successfully for the file ${FILE}."
```

In this script when i debug it then Disk available size not able to generate of target server using sftp connectivity & also if else condition `if [ ${FILE_SIZE} -lt ${DISK_AVAIL_SIZE} ]` is not working properly here. When i place temp.txt of 100MB file & disk available size is 85MB then it is moving 85MB file only not entire. Could you please help me here to print Disk available size of target server & if condition should work properly here in the script.

Comment: Why do you expect `sftp` to accept shell commands on standard input? It's not a shell interpreter. You can pass in a limited set of static commands with `sftp -b` but those are just simple text, not shell script.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee for your comment. Any idea how to get disk available size of another target server because i used sftp connectivity to connect to server but disk available size could not able to get.

Comment: copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and read [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) then fix your script accordingly and then let us know if you still have a problem.

Comment: You'll need `ssh` access to the remote machine. you can run cmds "against" the remote machine like `DiskFree=$(ssh usr@ip 'df -m /path/of/interest);echo "remDiskFree=${DiskFree}'` and do all your comparison and echo logic in a script that runs on your local machine. I searched for `[bash] [ssh] remote df`1 and numerous of the results had information that will help you.  Good luck.

Comment: Missed a closing single-quote before the closing `)`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't compare file size of one server & disk available size of another server. You can do 1 thing, take disk available size of target server in variable (eg:- $DISK_AVAIL_SIZE) and then you can compare with file size of main server. File size (stat -c %s) will give you in size in byte where `df ${SFTP_PATH}` will give you disk available size in kb so you have to convert file size into kb, just divide file size by 1024.

```
................
output=$(sftp -o BatchMode=yes -oPort=${SFTP_PORT} ${SFTP_USER}@${SFTP_HOST} <<EOF 
df ${SFTP_PATH}
EOF)
DISK_AVAIL_SIZE=$(echo $(output) | sed "s/sftp > df \$(output)//g" | awk '{printf("%s",$11)}')
echo ${DISK_AVAIL_SIZE}

if [ ${FILE_SIZE} -lt ${DISK_AVAIL_SIZE} ]
.....................
```

then you can compare file size & disk available size.

Comment: thanks yeah i got it. i declare the variable & then compare then its working now.

Answer (score 0):

$FILE_SIZE is a variable that exists on one machine, $DISK_AVAIL_SIZE should exist on the other machine. You can't compare 2 variables on two different machines.

In fact, using the `<<EOF` syntax expands some parts of the here document *before* it gets sent to the other machine. In particular, all unescaped variables are expanded, as well as backticks.

Therefore, the code sent to the other machine sees

```
DISK_AVAIL_SIZE=Filesystem                 1B-blocks        Used    Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/xxx 148683902976 10957774848 130098786304   8% /some/path
```

or whatever the output of the command is *on the source machine*.

Backslash the backquotes and backslash the dollar sign to prevent the expansion.

```
DISK_AVAIL_SIZE=\`df -B1 ${SFTP_PATH}/${tgt_path}\`
if [ ${FILE_SIZE} -lt \${DISK_AVAIL_SIZE} ]
```

Comment: Thanks @choroba for your answer but when I echo `$DISK_AVAIL_SIZE` in the script & in logs i could not able to see value of $DISK_AVAIL_SIZE.

Comment: Any idea how to get disk available size of another target server because i used sftp connectivity to connect to server but disk available size could not able to get.

Comment: @ShahinP: Have you escaped the dollar sign in `echo "Disk Available size = \${DISK_AVAIL_SIZE}"`, too? What was the output?

Comment: yes i used this one also but not able to get `DISK_AVAIL_SIZE` of target server.

Comment: @ShahinP: What was the output of `echo "Disk Available size = \${DISK_AVAIL_SIZE}"`?